# How to let "onmousemove" change image on different div?

Tags: javascript

please help me! I want when mouse move in different div, can show different image with mouse and when mouse left the div, it'll display:none, I did the first step, but image still work with mouse by only one div, I google three days but still can't find the answar...please help me, thanks very much! here is my code:

```
  <script>
          var img1 = document.getElementById("img1"),
            img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

          img1.onmouseover = function () {
            img2.style.display = "block";
            img2.style.opacity = "0.95";
          }
          img1.onmouseout = function () {
            img2.style.display = "none";
          }
          document.onmousemove = function (ev) {
            var oEvent = ev || event;
            var oDiv = document.getElementById('img2');
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
            oDiv.style.left = oEvent.clientX + scrollLeft + 'px';
            oDiv.style.top = oEvent.clientY + scrollTop + 'px';
          }

        </script>

        <script>
          var img3 = document.getElementById("img3"),
            img4 = document.getElementById("img4");

          img3.onmouseover = function () {
            img4.style.display = "block";
            img4.style.opacity = "0.95";
          }
          img3.onmouseout = function () {
            img4.style.display = "none";
          }

          document.onmousemove = function (ev) {
            var oEvent = ev || event;
            var oDiv = document.getElementById('img4');
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
            oDiv.style.left = oEvent.clientX + scrollLeft + 'px';
            oDiv.style.top = oEvent.clientY + scrollTop + 'px';
          }

        </script>

        <script>
          var img5 = document.getElementById("img5"),
            img6 = document.getElementById("img6");

          img5.onmouseover = function () {
            img6.style.display = "block";
            img6.style.opacity = "0.95";
          }
          img5.onmouseout = function () {
            img6.style.display = "none";
          }
          document.onmousemove = function (ev) {
            var oEvent = ev || event;
            var oDiv = document.getElementById('img6');
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
            oDiv.style.left = oEvent.clientX + scrollLeft + 'px';
            oDiv.style.top = oEvent.clientY + scrollTop + 'px';
          }

        </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this ?
But had to use hidden (properly visibility:hidden); display:none would in theory remove element so there will be no more mouse events. "hidden" works probably better here.

```js
var rootEl;
(function setup() {
  rootEl = document.getElementById("root");
  var imgs = rootEl.children;
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length - 1; i++) {
    imgs[i].onmouseover = containerOv;
    imgs[i].onmouseout = containerOut;
    imgs[i].onmousemove = containerMv;
  }
})() // (IIFE)
function report(e, img, collect) {
  var loc = e.type + ' ' + e.srcElement.id + ' -> ' + img.id;
  if (collect) rootEl.nextElementSibling.innerText += '\n' + loc;
  else rootEl.nextElementSibling.innerText = loc;
}

function containerOv() {
  var img = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling;
  img.style.display = "block";
  img.style.opacity = "0.95";

  report(event, img, 1);
}

function containerOut() {
  var img = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling;
  img.style.display = "hidden";

  report(event, img);
}

function containerMv() {
  var oDiv = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling;
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
  oDiv.style.left = event.clientX + scrollLeft + 'px';
  oDiv.style.top = event.clientY + scrollTop + 'px';

  report(event, oDiv, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <img id="img1" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7a4c467c7c34e0e9162535a801ae21a?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <img id="img2" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7a4c467c7c34e0e9162535a801ae21a?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <img id="img3" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7a4c467c7c34e0e9162535a801ae21a?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <img id="img4" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7a4c467c7c34e0e9162535a801ae21a?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <img id="img5" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7a4c467c7c34e0e9162535a801ae21a?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <img id="img6" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7a4c467c7c34e0e9162535a801ae21a?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
<span></span>
```